# Alternatives to switch case?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am trying to implement code where different actions are to be taken for different values of an integer `i`. The range of the integer will be from 1 to 50. The obvious solution to this problem would be to use `switch` cases, so that for different values of `i`, different functions are called. But I am wondering, is there any other better way to do this, rather than 50 `switch` case statements?

The following code shows what I am trying to do:

```
switch (i) {
case 1:
    function1();

case 2:
    function2();

case 3:
    function3()

...

case 50: 
    function50()
}
```

And the functions 1 to 50 are not related so, there is no way I can pass the int `i` as an argument to the function.

Comment: Another possible approach would be an array of functors or a map of functors. However, this question lacks sufficient detail to recommend any particular approach as better than another.

Comment: Can you give use "code".  It really depends on what you have on what would be better.

Comment: I edited the code to make it more clear what i am trying to do

Comment: @ichherzcplusplus This still doesn't really show what you're trying to accomplish, rather it shows the mechanism you have invented to solve the higher-level problem. What are you [really trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/218910)?

Comment: What's wrong for using `switch`?

Comment: Remember your break statement after each case unless you want it to run all the subsequent cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all your functions have the same signature, then an array of function pointers would work, eg:

```
typedef void (*func)();
func arr[50] = {&function1, &function2, &function3, ... &function50};
...
arr[i-1]();
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/V1hsaz)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from nested **if-else** (which could use binary-search-like nesting for speedup) you can use a **function-pointer array** or an **array of jump labels** (relies on the address of a label extension implemented by at least gcc, clang, and tinycc—i.e., `void *a = &&somelabel; goto *a;`).

You could look up your target function/label pointers via a more complex data structure than an array, but that would be an overkill if you have no more than 50 targets.

Answer (score 0):

If your `switch`'s arguments are spread out, you could use a map with function pointers or `std::function`'s. Here's an example with lambdas.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, std::function<void()>> funcs = {
        {10, [] { std::cout << "10\n"; }},
        {20, [] { std::cout << "20\n"; }},
        {45, [] { std::cout << "45\n"; }},
    };

    std::cout << "enter value: ";
    if(int i; std::cin >> i) {
        try {
            funcs.at(i)();
        } catch(const std::out_of_range&) {
            std::cout << "default\n";
        }
    }
}
```